# Why we can't use select * for particular table in join queries?

Tags: android, ios, mysql, sqlite

I want records from multiple tables. My requirement is to get all columns form one table and some interested columns from different table(s).

We can use "**select * from table_name**" for normal fetch query. But this is not working with join query, I have to write all column name for that table.

So, Is there any way to use * to fetch records in join query?

```
SELECT Item.ItemId, Item.Item, ItemIndex.CurrentAverageScore, ItemStyle.ItemStyleId, ItemStyle.ItemStyle, Brewery.BreweryId, Brewery.BreweryDescription, (SELECT PersonalRating FROM UserItemJournal WHERE ItemId = ItemIndex.ItemId) As PersonalRating, (SELECT Notes FROM UserItemJournal WHERE ItemId = ItemIndex.ItemId AND PersonalRating IS NOT NULL) As Notes FROM Item, ItemIndex, ItemStyle, Brewery, UserItemJournal WHERE Item.ItemId = ItemIndex.ItemId AND Item.LanguageId = 1 AND ItemStyle.ItemStyleId = ItemIndex.ItemStyleId AND ItemStyle.LanguageId = 1 AND Brewery.BreweryId = ItemIndex.BreweryId AND Brewery.LanguageId = 1 AND UserItemJournal.PersonalRating IS NOT NULL
```

In above query I want all columns from Item Table.
I think * has limitation, We can use * with single table only.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: show your work please

Comment: can you post ur query

Comment: Give me a minute please updating question with SQL query.

Comment: You shouldn't use SELECT * for anything more than a quick test anyway.  There's major efficiency issues with transfering all that extra data.  If your app is anything non-trivial you'll see significant increases by transfering only the columns you need.

Comment: select * is not working, i dont know when we can use * and when not. With signle table fetch * is working fine but with multiple table its not.

Comment: Need JOIN Query

Comment: I don't what kind of above query is?, I assumed above is inner join query. But the thing is i have multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that table name or aliase name and then dot star (item.*),
and other table columns as you like with their aliase or table name.

```
SELECT Item.*, ItemIndex.CurrentAverageScore, ItemStyle.ItemStyleId, ItemStyle.ItemStyle, Brewery.BreweryId, Brewery.BreweryDescription, (SELECT PersonalRating FROM UserItemJournal WHERE ItemId = ItemIndex.ItemId) As PersonalRating, (SELECT Notes FROM UserItemJournal WHERE ItemId = ItemIndex.ItemId AND PersonalRating IS NOT NULL) As Notes FROM Item, ItemIndex, ItemStyle, Brewery, UserItemJournal WHERE Item.ItemId = ItemIndex.ItemId AND Item.LanguageId = 1 AND ItemStyle.ItemStyleId = ItemIndex.ItemStyleId AND ItemStyle.LanguageId = 1 AND Brewery.BreweryId = ItemIndex.BreweryId AND Brewery.LanguageId = 1 AND UserItemJournal.PersonalRating IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you rams, I forgot to accept your answer here.